# Breaking up integral representations by convergence

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

A known integral takes the form of

$$\zeta(3)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^2}{e^t-1}dt$$

Through [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?s=1&_=1447006624853&i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bt%7D%7Be%5Et-1%7Ddt&fp=1&incTime=true) part of the integral converges to

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

which, I assume is due to the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function). Since the above part converges, can we break the integral into

$$\zeta(3)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt\int_{0}^{\infty} {t}\:dt=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\int_{0}^{\infty} {t}\:dt$$

Is my logic incorrect? Please let me know if I have made a mistake.

Comment: In general, $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}~dx~=~n!~\zeta(1+n),$$ and $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}~dx~=~n!~\eta(1+n).$$ See the [Riemann $\zeta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) functions for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect because $$\int_a^b f(x)\cdot g(x)dx\not\equiv\int_a^b f(x)dx\cdot\int_a^b g(x)dx$$

Comment: I thought so, is there any method to use the $\pi^2/6$ inside the integral representation? Integration by parts doesn't lead anywhere. Thanks for pointing the mistake out to me.

Comment: I don't think so, it would be too simple ;) But this is a beautiful thing in mathematics to try find something yourself. Then in both cases - when you succeed or not - you will learn something.